# Have to remove submit button to get js to work

Tags: javascript, html, json, button

I'm trying to validate login details from an html form. The problem is that the submit button doesn't work with the code. So for example if I leave the username and password blank it won't come up with an alert for "Invalid Username or Password". If I remove type="submit" it works but the button becomes an input text box with an onclick function which does not look good. I was provided with this code as it is a more secure way of passing login details than I had written so I have to confess my ignorance on JS and JSON so apologies if I haven't provided enough info but any guidance would be much appreciated on how to get the button working with the js. This is running on Chrome only. Cheers.

HTML code

```
        <form name="login" id="login-form">
            Username<input name="username" id="username" data-bind="value: username" type="text" value="" />                    
            Password<input name="password" id="password" data-bind="value: password" type="password" value="" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="myApp.getLogin()" value="Login" />
        </form>
```

JS

myApp.getLogin = function(){

```
var url = "http://localhost:8084/Alumni_JV1/services/login.json?username=" + myApp.vm.username() 
        + "&password=" + myApp.vm.password();
    console.log(url);
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {

    if(data.response==='success'){
        window.location.href="profile.jsp";
    }else{
        alert("Invalid Username or Password");
    }
});
```

};

Comment: try to add "return false;" at the end of the function

Comment: Where you write alert box code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A submit button is used to send form data to a server. E.G. `<form action='formHandler.php'>`. It would submit the form to the current URL if the `action` attribute isn't defined.

You can get a button without any action with `<input type='button' />`.

So changing `<input type='submit' ...` to `<input type='button' ...` should do the trick :)

Then the code would be:

```
    <form name="login" id="login-form">
        Username<input name="username" id="username" data-bind="value: username" type="text" value="" />                    
        Password<input name="password" id="password" data-bind="value: password" type="password" value="" />
        <input name="submit" type="button" onclick="myApp.getLogin()" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Great! Just remember to mark it the answer if it satisfies you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change input type=submit field with button tag.